# django static file not loading

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have a problem. I did everything as described in [this Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial06/) (EDIT: dead link, here's [a working link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907091745/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial06/)), and everything is running fine, but CSS and images are not showing up/being applied. How do I get the CSS and images to show up properly? Thanks for any help.

My CSS style file:

```css
li a {
    color: red;
}
body {
    background: white url("images/background.gif") no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from polls import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'), 
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**index.html**

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/polls/style.css' %}"/>
{% if latest_poll_list %}
<ul>
{% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**settings.py**

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/polls/static/'
    )
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'C:/django poll project/mysite/templates',
    )

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'polls',
)
```

On `runserver` command, getting:

```
[18/Sep/2014 17:40:51] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 311
[18/Sep/2014 18:25:39] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 311
```

Comment: Where did you put your CSS file?

Comment: \django poll project\polls\static\polls\style.css

Comment: Implement this code inside your project: Visit this link: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132733/how-run-static-file-when-debug-is-false>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The URL to the static-Files is "yourDomain/static/"

When you want to access to your "style.css" you should use "/static/style.css" instead of "/polls/style.css"

**EDIT:**

Change this part of your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/polls/static/'
    )
```

to

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/django poll project/mysite/static'
    )
```

better would be:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'static'),
)
```

Then the folder is called "static" and is on the same level where the "manage.py" is. When you put your style.css in this "static"-folder you can call it with "/static/style.css"

Comment: Doesn't reflect any changes

Comment: Worked for me like this: `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/projectpath/static',)`.

Answer (score 17):

### Updated Answer For Django 2.2 - 2019

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

> BASE_DIR is already defined in `settings.py`

Also when loading, do `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: NOTICE: it's a tuple. Don't forget the comma at the end.

Comment: NOTICE: It can also be a list. like
```
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Answer (score 5):

**for Django version 4 2022**

if anyone's static file is not working,make sure your static folder is in the right location

shortcut:
Keep your **static** folder in the same directory where your database is located.

```
-->ProjectName
  -->app1
  -->app2
  -->db.sqlite3
  -->static
```

[image]

and make sure you have added this lines in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
BASE_DIR/'static',
)
```

Comment: I am getting "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting." error message.   It just doesn't want to pull the static files, always gives "not found" error for all my static files.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', 'static'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If problem bad variable `{{STATIC_URL}}` in template files, add

```py
'django.template.context_processors.static'
```

to this part of `settings.py` module:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': TEMPLATE_DIRS,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

And restarting the server worked for me

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `django.contrib.staticfiles` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. Set `STATIC_ROOT` to the drive folder with the static files.
3. Set `STATIC_URL` to the browser folder/prefix that will point at the files.

The problem is `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` cannot be in the same folder and try to act differently...

`STATICFILES_DIRS`

- exists because different installable apps have different static resources.
- Through django magic, in development these files are served from each app.
- This allows editing assets and re-running the server without worrying about the `STATIC_ROOT` cache.
- Also requires a collector that assembles static files into `STATIC_ROOT`.

`STATIC_ROOT`

- The place the files are served from in production.
- A simple browser path to folder mapping.
- Not recommended for production because usually *`NGINX`* or AppEngine handles this.
- Works because you are skipping the collector and telling Django to look here always.
- Will not work if an app has its own assets, you will need to use `STATIC_DIRS`.

Answer (score 1):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently works on Django Version 3.x

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello user!</h1>
        <p>something you want</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

To work above Implementation Following code must be added in project setting file.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
 ]
```

Here static is a directory in project root.

Answer (score 0):

For the newer version of Django use the following command. It solved my issues.

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
'/var/www/static/',
]

{% load static %}

I followed this documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score -1):

When you run 'python manage.py runserver' add any post number like 2000 or whatever it will look like 'python manage.py runserver 2000' it will solve the problem

Comment: Well, it is used for changing port only, and we can also change IP, this is not an answer, with high respect I am saying to you :).

Comment: totally irrelevant answer to the question asked